# sending continuous text data from java code to html via http request

Tags: javascript, java, angularjs

I am working on developing an application where i am am doing http post request via angular and then this request is received by Java code, code does its stuff and generate logs of about 50-60 lines creating one line every seconds.
I want to show these logs on my html page as they generate, right now i am collecting all logs and displaying them once the request finishes?
Can this be done in continuous manner?

JAVA CODE

Java code create array of logs of size 50-60, it takes 60-90 seconds to finish the operation, and i am sending array with below code after converting it to JSON

response.getWriter.write(applogs)

JAVASCRIPT CODE

```
var httpPostData = function (postparameters,postData){

return $http ({           
method  : 'POST',
url     : URL,
params  : postparameters,
headers: headers,
data    : postData
}).success (function (responseData){
     return responseData.data;
})
}

var addAppPromise = httpPostData (restartAppParams,app);
    addAppPromise.then(function (logs){
      $scope.logs = logs.data;
})
```

HTML Code

```
<span ng-repeat="log in logs">{{log}}<br></span>
```

Comment: Can you host a websocket endpoint in your javacode and then consume it using something like angular-websocket?  https://github.com/AngularClass/angular-websocket

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options:

1. (Uglier but faster and easier one) Make your service respond immediately (don't wait for 'stuff' to be generated) and create second service
   that would return logs created so far. Then in JS implement polling: call this second service in short, fixed intervals and update view.
2. Use [EventSource](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/API/EventSource) to get server sent events .
   You can also use websockets, but since you only want your server to
   feed client, EventSource should be enough. However, keep in mind that this API will require polyfills for IE/Edge and special handling on the server side.